# Estimate the result size of an SQL request in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I setup a postgres + nodejs system that performs queries based on user inputs. As the server resources are constrained I want to prevent a query from having a too big result that won't fit in RAM or go over a limit I've set.

The query generation can get a bit complex depending on the inputs and the table I query looks like the following:

```
id | id_something_related | timestamp | varchar32_A | varchar32_B | jsonb_data  (with different names of course)
```

As the table contains a jsonb data (non-fixed size), I cannot use a simple LIMIT to stop on a maximum row count.

The solution I have for the moment is to perform a second query, that encapsulates the first and returns its size:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(pg_column_size( _data.* )), 0) as total_size_byte FROM ( ...REAL QUERY HERE.... ) as _data
```

This first query gives me a size that I can use to decide whether I'm gonna execute the query or not.
The counterpart is that it runs the query 2 times which represents a substantial overhead on the server.

I will be happy with:

- A query syntax that prevents too large results in Bytes
- A query that can estimate the result size of another query (but that runs faster at the cost of some precision)
- A query system that allows me to get the result size to decide if I want to download it (like a temporary buffer held by postgres). Notice that DB is on the same server so I don't want postgres to fill the RAM either)
- A postgres setting to set a maximum result size
- A nodejs option to stop the download of the query result when it reaches a given size. (I'm using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)
- Any other solutions (Notice that loosing a too large result isn't an issue)

Comment: You could run `explain` and then use the estimates from there (rows and width). If you use XML or JSON as the output format, it's quite easy to parse.

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer, I will use the Cursor solution and as I rune the queries in nodejs, I'm referring to https://node-postgres.com/api/cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple and classical solution to this problem is to use a cursor and fetch the results one by one or in batches. Then you can simply stop fetching as soon as your limit is exceeded.

Any other solution will have to rely on estimates and is therefore inexact. You can examine the result of `EXPLAIN` for the query as shown at the end of [this blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/). Since you are not only after the row count, but also the size of each row, you would also want to retrieve the `width` of the average result row (in bytes).

But I think that using a cursor is the king's way.